# Exposing an EventListener outside of the cluster using a LoadBalancer Service type tekton gcp k8

Tags: kubernetes, tekton, tekton-pipelines, tekton-trigger

Exposing an EventListener outside of the cluster, we can expose this service using the below options

1. Using a LoadBalancer Service type
2. Using a Kubernetes Ingress object
3. Using the NGINX Ingress Controller
4. Using OpenShift Route

I am using a LoadBalancer Service type in the GCP Kubernetes cluster to trigger the event listener. I have the below tekton event listener

```
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: EventListener
metadata:
  name: bitbucket-listener
  namespace: fetebird-common
spec:
  serviceAccountName: gcp-service-account
  triggers:
    - name: bitbucket-triggers
      interceptors:
        - ref:
            name: "bitbucket"
          params:
            - name: eventTypes
              value:
                - repo:push
      bindings:
        - ref: bitbucket-trigger-binding
      template:
        ref: bitbucket-trigger-template
```

**I have created a Load Balancer service as below**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bitbucket-eventlistener-lb
  namespace: fetebird-common
spec:
  selector:
    eventlistener: bitbucket-listener
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 30580  # Adjust this to the actual target port of your EventListener
  type: LoadBalancer
```

The external Ip of the cluster, is as below

```
kubectl get svc bitbucket-eventlistener-lb -n fetebird-common -o wide
NAME                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE     SELECTOR
bitbucket-eventlistener-lb   LoadBalancer   10.60.9.24   35.193.230.47   80:30758/TCP   5m49s   eventlistener=bitbucket-listener
```

**CURL**

```
curl -v \
-H 'X-Event-Key: repo:push' \
-d '{"push": {"changes":[{"old":{}, "new":{"name":"bb-cloud-test-1"}}]},"repository":{"links": {"html":{"href": "https://bitbucket.org/savitaredhat/bitbuckettest-customer"}},"name":"bitbuckettest-customer"}, "actor":{"display_name": "savita"}}' \
http://35.193.230.47
```

**Exception**

```
*   Trying 35.193.230.47:80...
* connect to 35.193.230.47 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 35.193.230.47 port 80 after 203 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.193.230.47 port 80 after 203 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

**With PORT Exception**

```
*   Trying 35.193.230.47:30758...
* connect to 35.193.230.47 port 30758 failed: Operation timed out
* Failed to connect to 35.193.230.47 port 30758 after 75004 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 35.193.230.47 port 30758 after 75004 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding resources worked for me

```
spec:
  serviceAccountName: gcp-service-account
  resources:
    kubernetesResource:
      serviceType: LoadBalancer
```

**Full code**

```
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: EventListener
metadata:
  name: bitbucket-listener
  namespace: fetebird-common
spec:
  serviceAccountName: gcp-service-account
  resources:
    kubernetesResource:
      serviceType: LoadBalancer
  triggers:
    - name: bitbucket-triggers
      interceptors:
        - ref:
            name: "bitbucket"
          params:
            - name: secretRef
              value:
                secretName: git-ssh-key-secret
                secretKey: ssh-privatekey
            - name: eventTypes
              value:
                - repo:push
      bindings:
        - ref: bitbucket-trigger-binding
      template:
        ref: bitbucket-trigger-template
```

Comment: The `EventListener` controller already provisions a `Service` object, so making that of `LoadBalancer` type is better than creating an extra service.

Alternatively, using an `Ingress` that points to the `Service` created by the `EventListener` controller works well for me, [this](https://github.com/tektoncd/plumbing/blob/main/tekton/ci/infra/ingress.yaml) is the `Ingress` we use for Tekton own infrastructure setup.

Answer (score 0):

Since event listener provision a service, we can get the service using below command

```
kubectl get svc -n <NAME_SPACE>
```

The name should start with `el-`

**With Ingress**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: bitbucket-tekton-ingress
  namespace: fetebird-common
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: el-bitbucket-listener
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Onces the ingress is created

```
kubectl describe ingress <INGRESS_NAME> -n <NAME_SPACE>
```

[image]

We can use this IP in webhook